# Twitter: follow another user's followers

Tags: php, perl, twitter

I want to follow all of a particular users followers on Twitter.

What's the best way of doing this?

I'd like to get all of their twitter usernames too.

I can program in any language really (except Lisp!)

Comment: Note that 1) you're using the word "best" in your question (a red flag for "not constructive"), and 2) the use case for this seems to be spam.  This might explain some of the downvotes you are getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at the Twitter [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api), in particular [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids).

Answer (score 2):

in pseudocode:

```
foreach follower in competitor.followers
  me.follow(follower);
next
```

competitors.followers can be got via [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)

you can programatically follow a user via [POST friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create)

which will return details of the user followed which will probably let you get their twitter name, if not then you can get the details of the user from their id using [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`Net::Twitter`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTwitter) on [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the API guide, esp. the section about [Friends & Followers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)

Comment: Thanks for that... I'll have a look now.

Comment: No problem. No spamming now!  ;-)